# Calculating age in a certain month in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, string-comparison

I need to extraxt a list of users who turn 15 years old in any day in a certain month (e.g. in June or in July) and I am trying to use string comparison in SQL Server (stored procedure) but it is not working.

I get `@Month` parameter from a SSRS which is given from a dropdown list of next 10 months. (some of this month will be in the next year).

I have an **Age** function which converts a date format from `27/07/2003` (BirthDate) to a string `15 years,2 months,27 days`. Naturally, There are people aged `9 years, 0 months, 2 days` as well.

So far, I could write the code to check if the person will be 15 and at least 1 month (`15 years,1 months`) in next July (`@Month + 1`) supposing we want to know if they turn 15 in June (`@Month`) but still it is not working because of string comparison.

`Age(BirthDate, GETDATE())` is the function which turns age in this format:
`15 years,2 months,27 days` as string.

I hope it is clear what I mean.

```
declare @Age varchar (20) = 15,
@Month varchar (25) = 'June',
@CurrentMonth varchar (20) = null,


SET @CurrentMonth = DATENAME(month, GETDATE());  /* returns current month in string */

SELECT My_ID
    ,Title
    ,FirstName
    ,LastName
    ,Gender
    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR, BirthDate, 103) AS BirthDate
    ,dbo.Age(BirthDate, GETDATE()) AS Age
    ,LocalityName AS Locality
    ,GETDATE() AS ReportDate
    ,MONTH(GETDATE()) AS MONTH
    ,YEAR(GETDATE()) AS YEAR
FROM dbo.vw_individuals
WHERE (LEFT(dbo.Age(BirthDate, DATEADD(month, 1 +
        (SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH, @CurrentMonth + ' 01 2010', @Month + ' 01 2010')
         + CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH, @CurrentMonth + ' 01 2010', @Month + ' 01 2010') < 0 THEN 12 ELSE 0 END) 
    , GETDATE())), 2) = @Age)   
    AND (LEFT(dbo.Age(BirthDate, DATEADD(month, 1 +
        (SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH, @CurrentMonth + ' 01 2010', @Month + ' 01 2010')
         + CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH, @CurrentMonth + ' 01 2010', @Month + ' 01 2010') < 0 THEN 12 ELSE 0 END)
    , GETDATE())), 16) < @Age + ' years,2 month')

    AND (month(convert(DATETIME, BirthDate, 103)) = (SELECT DATEPART(MM, @Month + '01 2010'))) /* Checks if the BirthDate month is the same as the chosen month (@Month) */
```

Comment: Why does your `WHERE` clause need to use string comparisons? Your output has the dates formatted a certain way, but as far as I can tell, there's no reason why the selection logic has to compare based on the output format.

Comment: @mypetlion because I need to take only people who turn 15 that is why I should use `LEFT...2) = @Age` and `< @Age + ' years,2 month'`

Comment: **"I need to extract a list of users who turn 15 years old in any day in a certain month (e.g. in June or in July)"** So why isn't your WHERE clause simply this: `BirthDate BETWEEN '2003-06-01' and '2003-06-30'`?

Comment: Sorry @Zack. I added more description in the body. The year could be current or next year and the query can be run in any month and any year.

Answer (score 3):

so given the @Month and @Year you're interested in, then the people you need are given BY

```
  SELECT ..... WHERE YEAR(BirthDate) = @YEAR - 15 AND Month(BirthDate) = @Month
```

so all the people returned have a 15th birthday in @Month/@Year

-- bit of a pain though, might not quite work if a person is born 29th February, they turn 15 in March although that will never be a leap year, so you could get away with

```
SELECT ..... WHERE YEAR(BirthDate) = @YEAR - 15 
               AND Month(BirthDate) 
                  + CASE WHEN MONTH(Birthdate) = 2 AND DAY(Birthdate) = 29 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
                       = @Month
```

Answer (score 0):

Below should show you way to go, your query is much too complicated for what you need (I think), just use logic from my `IF` in your `WHERE`

```
declare @dob datetime = '2003-10-13 17:21:45.620'

if(month(@dob) = month(getdate()) 
AND year(@dob)+15 = year(getdate()))
    print '15 years old this month'
else
    print 'not 15 years old this month'
```

The same yoke, just used table variable:

```
declare @dob datetime = '2003-10-13 17:21:45.620'
declare @t table (dob datetime)
insert into @t
values ('2003-10-13 17:21:45.620'), ('2004-10-13 17:21:45.620'), ('2003-10-30 17:21:45.620')

select *
from @t
where month(dob) = month(getdate()) 
    and year(dob)+15 = year(getdate())
```

**EDIT**

Other way to achieve what you need is to use `DATEDIFF`

```
declare @dob datetime = '2003-10-13 17:21:45.620'
declare @t table (dob datetime)
insert into @t
values ('2003-10-13 17:21:45.620'), 
    ('2004-10-13 17:21:45.620'), 
    ('2003-10-30 17:21:45.620')

select *
from @t
where datediff(month, dob, getdate()) = 180 --(15 years * 12months)
```